# The returned text by "context.document.getSelection()" not runs for special characters

Tags: office-js, office365api, word-addins

I want to get the selected text by the user to search into the rest of document using the next code:

```
  await window.Word.run(async (context) => {
    const recorder = context.document.getSelection()
    recorder.load(['text'])
    await context.sync()

    console.log('Selected text: ', recorder.text)
    ....
  })
```

But the text found for the next selection:
[image: selected character]

is the next:
[image: value of the selected text]

then when I use this value to search instead to find the correct values then it is being found the wrong character "("

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with this solution is that only for this character, the ooxml result from returned range by getSelection contains 6282 lines. How can I know what is the correct and extract the value for the character?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The text property do not contain special characters, which is by design. If you need to exam the special property with a range, you can first get the OOXML of the range and then check the OOXML returned.